# Http Response Python

Tags: python, django

like the response.json() does not display anything but on the other hand the response.text displays the results
how to loop through response.text
Exemple de mon code

```
def api:
  url = 'http://api-content/product/GetProduct'
  x = requests.get(url)
  content=x.text

"produits":[{
    "des":"blaa",
     "cont":"sdf"
 }]
```

Merci de votre aide

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you want to loop through? In a big block of text, what would you use to determine what is index 0, 1, 2, 3?

Comment: Please post _entirely_ in English. Give a [mre]. How is Django relevant?

Comment: Maybe it's not a valid Json. the snippet below the **Def** doesn't look correct.. it should be wrapped in another dictionary

Comment: @Néalium , how to wrap it in another dictionary

Comment: They doing `json.loads(x.text)` and if crashes then it's not a valid Json.. and I'd do something ghetto like `data = json.loads('{'+x.text+'}')` to wrap it.. it would make *No* sense for it to not be valid json tho- but you never know

Answer (score 0):

I always do `json.loads(x.text)` and that seems to work for me

```py
def api:
  url = 'http://api-content/product/GetProduct'
  x = requests.get(url)
  import json
  r = json.loads(x.text)
  for i in r:
      print(i)
```

Comment: That's the same thing the json method _already does_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Good to know. I've never done that or saw it before, so I just posted what I know works for me 100% of the time.